# pip3 install cytoolz web3 : EOF ran out of input

Tags: fedora, pip, python3

Working on Fedora 29, I want to install web3.py, using pip.
In theory `sudo pip3 install web3` works, but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
ERROR: running egg_info
creating pip-egg-info/cytoolz.egg-info
writing pip-egg-info/cytoolz.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/cytoolz.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to pip-egg-info/cytoolz.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/cytoolz.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/cytoolz.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/lib2to3/pgen2/grammar.py", line 108, in load
        d = pickle.load(f)
    EOFError: Ran out of input
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-req-build-rrup96_c/
```

Python3.7, pip3 up-to-date, setuptools up-to-date.

Since the error is generated during the installation of cytoolz, I tried to manually install it, first with `pip3 install cytoolz`, then by downloading the tar.gz from pypi.org, for the latest release (9.0.1.0) and the former (9.0.0). Tried reinstalling pip3, clearing the `.cache/pip` from /root and ~/. Always the same error.

As a side note, `pip3 install requests` works just fine.

Google has no clue about the `EOFError` with cytoolz. As suggested, it seems the error is thrown by `pickle.load(f)`, so maybe it's trying to read a non-existing file. But the entire stack trace leaves me clueless about which file it could be. As I have tried to install several versions, I tend to think the missing file is not a cytoolz one.

I've been on this for many hours and exhausted by the lack of information.
Any hint/solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please paste (via a comment) the requirements errors and dnf list installed | grep -E '^pip'

Comment: @linuxdev2013 You misunderstood me, I do not have any requirements errors. Google would only give me recommendations about requirements errors, which I do not get any.
`python3-pip.noarch   18.1-1.fc29   @updates` for pip with dnf, note that dnf do not list any other pip installation.
`$ pip3 --version` gives me `pip 19.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)`

Comment: It looks like `pickle` is trying to read an empty (non-existent?) file.

Comment: @Anaksunaman Indeed, do you have any idea where I should look for ?